# como acessar um SQL 64 bits

Tags: visual-basic-6, odbc

Tenho um *software* em `vb6` 32 *bits*, numa estação de 32 *bits* acessando um banco de dados `SQL` 64 *bits* em um servidor 64 *bits*. Como criar a ODBC?

Comment: Marcelo, tentou fazer algum código, está a receber algum erro? Que linguagem está utilizando? Edite sua pergunta e adicione mais detalhes.

Comment: o erro acontece quando eu estou tentando criar a odbc. o erro é : sql server error:17 - server inexistente ou acesso negado

Comment: Marcelos clique no link [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/74962/edit) a baixo da sua pergunta e adicione esses detalhes, mensagens de erro o código que você está tentando e etc...

Comment: acredito que o fato de a estação ser 32 e o server 64 não tem nada a ver com seu problema. De outra máquina consegue conectar ? Verifique se o SQL está aceitando conexões TCP